# Kill -SIGTERM and KILLSIG: Safely terminating applications

Tags: c, linux

On a Linux system, the signal -KILLTERM sends a signal that allows applications to safely shut down. These questions might be a little theoretical, but I want to understand them.

1. When a system sends a terminate signal, where is it sent?
2. What allows time for the process or, application, to 'safely' terminate?
3. Is there a child process, or something similar, that runs in the background of an application that looks for this signal?

These questions stem from the Linux watchdog, in reading the man page I saw that the process of the watchdog is to first send a terminate signal to a given PID, and then a KILL -9 signal to force it. I want to be able to utilize the safety built in to the watchdog.

Comment: Signals dont kill processes, people (and their processes) send signals to kill processes.

Comment: The TERM signal can be caught by a process's signal handler; KILL cannot. Therefore the watchdog tries sending SIGTERM first and waits for some time, so any process that uses a custom SIGTERM handler has time to execute it. "Safe" termination is something built into an application by the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void cleanUp(){ // Do whatever you want here
    printf("Safely terminating \n");
}

void hand(int sig){ // called when you are sent SIGTERM
    /*
    Here you can safely terminate..
    */
    atexit(cleanUp); // call cleanUp at exit.
    exit(0);
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGTERM, hand); //Assign function to be called on SIGTERM
    /*
    Your code goes here.
    I have put an infinite loop for demonstration.
    */
    printf("Started execution..\n");
    for(;;);
}
```

This shows how a function can be assigned to be called when a signal is delivered to your application.

To deliver the signal `SIGTERM` to this code, do this,

```
kill -SIGTERM <pid>
```

Here, `<pid>` id the process id of your running program.

Comment: Note you should not use printf() and friends inside a signal handler. printf() is not signal-safe.

Comment: @joop I agree. This was just to demonstrate how all this works as OP asked.

Comment: Well it is a bad demonstration, since it demonstrates bad practice.

Comment: I've had it drilled into my head that one should only set a flag inside a signal handler and have the work loop check the flag, for the reason joop mentioned.

Comment: @joop Okay, I'll change it.

Comment: @joop Is this better ?

Comment: I don't know; I can imagine that atexit() isn't signal safe either. (it *could* use a linked list + malloc internally)

Comment: @joop Thought you might find this interesting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar thank you. I have a follow up question question now. After playing around with the signal function, I see that it interrupts the application no matter what in app process is being executed. Is there a method of blocking signals  while handling data, etc, without being redirected to the signal handler? Essentially, it waits until safe to call the signal handle. I played with the idea of creating a user defined signal, and then blocking -SIGTERM. but this seems over complicated, and I wonder if there is a simpler way?